# Cross Compiling ROS Kinetic for ARM Cortex-A7

Tags: ros, compile, ros-kinetic, rospack, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am currently working on cross compiling ROS Kinetic for an ARM Cortex-A7. I build the image for my module with buildroot. This is where I get my necessary dependencies compiled. (log4cxx, boost 1.58, tinyxml, python2.7)

I downloaded the ROS Kinetic Bare Bones files with:

```
$ rosinstall_generator ros_comm --rosdistro kinetic --deps --wet-only --tar > kinetic-ros_comm-wet.rosinstall
$ wstool init -j8 src kinetic-ros_comm-wet.rosinstall
```

So far I can compile until package 26/52.

The files are compiled with the following command:

```
./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/ros_files_comm/src/rostoolchain.cmake --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBoost_DEBUG=ON
```

I use the following rostoolchain.cmake file:

## File: rostoolchain.cmake

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE arm-linux-gnueabihf)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR /opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include)
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR /opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib)
#set(BOOST_ROOT /opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include/boost)
set(TinyXML_LIBRARY /opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/)
set(PYTHON_LIBRARY /opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/python2.7)

set(console_bridge_DIR /opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/cmake/console_bridge)


# Have to set this one to BOTH, to allow CMake to find rospack
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

But I receive following Errors:

```
#Output
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
-- filesystem
-- program_options
-- system
-- Found PythonLibs: /opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/python2.7   (found suitable version "2.7.14", minimum required is "2.7") 
-- Found TinyXML: /opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/  
-- Configuring done
WARNING: Target "rosstackexe" requests linking to directory "/opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "rosstackexe" requests linking to directory "/opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/python2.7".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "rospackexe" requests linking to directory "/opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "rospackexe" requests linking to directory "/opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/python2.7".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "rospack" requests linking to directory "/opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "rospack" requests linking to directory "/opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/python2.7".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "rospack-utest" requests linking to directory "/opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "rospack-utest" requests linking to directory "/opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/python2.7".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/Desktop/TCG4_ROS/ros_files_comm/build_isolated/rospack
==> make -j4 -l4 in '/home/user/Desktop/TCG4_ROS/ros_files_comm/build_isolated/rospack'
Scanning dependencies of target rospack
[ 11%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rospack.dir/src/rospack.cpp.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rospack.dir/src/rospack_backcompat.cpp.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rospack.dir/src/rospack_cmdline.cpp.o
[ 44%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rospack.dir/src/utils.cpp.o
In file included from /opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:8:0,
 from /home/user/Desktop/TCG4_ROS/ros_files_comm/src/rospack/src/rospack.cpp:72:
/opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include/python2.7    /pyconfig.h:1193:0: warning: "_POSIX_C_SOURCE" redefined
 #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L

In file included from /opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/7.2.1/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/os_defines.h:39:0,
from /opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/7.2.1/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/c++config.h:533,
from /opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/7.2.1/cstddef:49,
from /opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include/boost/tr1/detail/config.hpp:9,
from /opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include/boost/tr1/unordered_set.hpp:8,
from /home/user/Desktop/TCG4_ROS/ros_files_comm/src/rospack/include/rospack/rospack.h:108,
from /home/user/Desktop/TCG4_ROS/ros_files_comm/src/rospack/src/rospack.cpp:28:
/opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include/features.h:257:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 # define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

In file included from /opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:8:0,
from /home/user/Desktop/TCG4_ROS/ros_files_comm/src/rospack/src/rospack.cpp:72:
/opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:1215:0: warning: "_XOPEN_SOURCE" redefined
 #define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600

In file included from /opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/7.2.1/arm-    linux-gnueabihf/bits/os_defines.h:39:0,
from /opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/7.2.1/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/c++config.h:533,
from /opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/7.2.1/cstddef:49,
from /opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include/boost/tr1/detail/config.hpp:9,
from /opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include/boost/tr1/unordered_set.hpp:8,
from /home/user/Desktop/TCG4_ROS/ros_files_comm/src/rospack/include/rospack/rospack.h:108,
from /home/user/Desktop/TCG4_ROS/ros_files_comm/src/rospack/src/rospack.cpp:28:
/opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include/features.h:198:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
# define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700

[ 55%] Linking CXX shared library /home/user/Desktop/TCG4_ROS/ros_files_comm/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so
[ 55%] Built target rospack
Scanning dependencies of target rosstackexe
Scanning dependencies of target rospackexe
[ 77%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rospackexe.dir/src/rospack_main.cpp.o
[ 77%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rosstackexe.dir/src/rosstack_main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable /home/user/Desktop/TCG4_ROS/ros_files_comm/devel_isolated/rospack/bin/rospack
[100%] Linking CXX executable /home/user/Desktop/TCG4_ROS/ros_files_comm/devel_isolated/rospack/bin/rosstack
//home/homeuser//userDesktop//DesktopTCG4_ROS//TCG4_ROSros_files_comm            //ros_files_commdevel_isolated//devel_isolatedrospack//rospacklib//liblibrospack.so/:librospack.so :undefined      undefinedreference  referenceto  to` PyTuple_SetItem`'PyTuple_SetItem
'/
home//homeuser//userDesktop//DesktopTCG4_ROS//TCG4_ROSros_files_comm    //ros_files_commdevel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.so: undefined reference/ todevel_isolated /`rospackPy_InitializeEx/'lib
//librospack.sohome:/ userundefined/ Desktopreference/ TCG4_ROSto/     ros_files_comm`/Py_InitializeExdevel_isolated'/
rospack//homelib//userlibrospack.so/:Desktop /undefinedTCG4_ROS /referenceros_files_comm /todevel_isolated     /`rospackvtable/ libfor/ librospack.soTiXmlDocument:' 
undefined/ homereference/ userto/ Desktop`/vtableTCG4_ROS /forros_files_comm /TiXmlDocumentdevel_isolated'/
rospack//homelib//userlibrospack.so/:Desktop /undefinedTCG4_ROS /referenceros_files_comm /todevel_isolated     /`rospackPyDict_GetItemString/'lib
//librospack.sohome:/ userundefined/ Desktopreference/ TCG4_ROSto/     ros_files_comm`/PyDict_GetItemStringdevel_isolated'/
rospack//homelib//userlibrospack.so/:Desktop /undefinedTCG4_ROS /referenceros_files_comm /todevel_isolated     /`rospackTiXmlNode/:lib:/~librospack.soTiXmlNode:( )undefined' 
reference/ hometo/ user`/TiXmlNodeDesktop:/:TCG4_ROS~/TiXmlNoderos_files_comm(/)devel_isolated'/
rospack//homelib//userlibrospack.so/:Desktop /undefinedTCG4_ROS /referenceros_files_comm /todevel_isolated     /`rospackPyModule_GetDict/'lib
//librospack.sohome:/ userundefined/ Desktopreference/ TCG4_ROSto/     ros_files_comm`/PyModule_GetDictdevel_isolated'/
rospack//homelib//userlibrospack.so/:Desktop /undefinedTCG4_ROS /referenceros_files_comm /todevel_isolated     /`rospackPyTuple_New/'lib
//librospack.sohome:/ userundefined/ Desktopreference/ TCG4_ROSto/     ros_files_comm`/PyTuple_Newdevel_isolated'/
rospack//homelib//userlibrospack.so/:Desktop /undefinedTCG4_ROS /referenceros_files_comm /todevel_isolated     /`rospack_Py_NoneStruct/'lib
//librospack.sohome:/ userundefined/ Desktopreference/ TCG4_ROSto/     ros_files_comm`/_Py_NoneStructdevel_isolated'/
rospack//homelib//userlibrospack.so/:Desktop /undefinedTCG4_ROS /referenceros_files_comm /todevel_isolated     /`rospackTiXmlNode/:lib:/FirstChildElementlibrospack.so(:char  undefinedconst *reference)  toconst '`
TiXmlNode/:home:/FirstChildElementuser(/charDesktop /constTCG4_ROS*/)ros_files_comm /constdevel_isolated'/
rospack//homelib//userlibrospack.so/:Desktop /undefinedTCG4_ROS /referenceros_files_comm /todevel_isolated     /`rospackPyObject_CallObject/'lib
//librospack.sohome:/ userundefined/ Desktopreference/ TCG4_ROSto/     ros_files_comm`/PyObject_CallObjectdevel_isolated'/
rospack//homelib//userlibrospack.so/:Desktop /undefinedTCG4_ROS /referenceros_files_comm /todevel_isolated     /`rospackPyString_FromString/'lib
//librospack.sohome:/ userundefined/ Desktopreference/ TCG4_ROSto/     ros_files_comm`/PyString_FromStringdevel_isolated'/
rospack//homelib//userlibrospack.so/:Desktop /undefinedTCG4_ROS /referenceros_files_comm /todevel_isolated     /`rospackTiXmlDocument/:lib:/TiXmlDocumentlibrospack.so(:) 'undefined
 /referencehome /touser /`DesktopTiXmlDocument/:TCG4_ROS:/TiXmlDocumentros_files_comm(/)devel_isolated'/
rospack//homelib//userlibrospack.so/:Desktop /undefinedTCG4_ROS /referenceros_files_comm /todevel_isolated     /`rospackPyGILState_Release/'lib
//librospack.sohome:/ userundefined/ Desktopreference/ TCG4_ROSto/     ros_files_comm`/PyGILState_Releasedevel_isolated'/
rospack//homelib//userlibrospack.so/:Desktop /undefinedTCG4_ROS /referenceros_files_comm /todevel_isolated     /`rospackTiXmlNode/:lib:/FirstChildElementlibrospack.so(:)  undefinedconst 'reference
 /tohome /`userTiXmlNode/:Desktop:/FirstChildElementTCG4_ROS(/)ros_files_comm /constdevel_isolated'/
rospack//homelib//userlibrospack.so/:Desktop /undefinedTCG4_ROS /referenceros_files_comm /todevel_isolated     /`rospackTiXmlElement/:lib:/Attributelibrospack.so(:char  undefinedconst *reference)  toconst '`
TiXmlElement/:home:/Attributeuser(/charDesktop /constTCG4_ROS*/)ros_files_comm /constdevel_isolated'/
rospack//homelib//userlibrospack.so/:Desktop /undefinedTCG4_ROS /referenceros_files_comm /todevel_isolated     /`rospackPyObject_IsTrue/'lib
//librospack.sohome:/ userundefined/ Desktopreference/ TCG4_ROSto/     ros_files_comm`/PyObject_IsTruedevel_isolated'/
rospack//homelib//userlibrospack.so/:Desktop /undefinedTCG4_ROS /referenceros_files_comm /todevel_isolated     /`rospackTiXmlElement/:lib:/GetTextlibrospack.so(:)  undefinedconst 'reference
 /tohome /`userTiXmlElement/:Desktop:/GetTextTCG4_ROS(/)ros_files_comm /constdevel_isolated'/
rospack//homelib//userlibrospack.so/:Desktop /undefinedTCG4_ROS /referenceros_files_comm /todevel_isolated     /`rospackPyCallable_Check/'lib
//librospack.sohome:/ userundefined/ Desktopreference/ TCG4_ROSto/     ros_files_comm`/PyCallable_Checkdevel_isolated'/
rospack//homelib//userlibrospack.so/:Desktop /undefinedTCG4_ROS /referenceros_files_comm /todevel_isolated     /`rospackTiXmlNode/:lib:/IterateChildrenlibrospack.so(:char  undefinedconst *reference,  toTiXmlNode  `constTiXmlNode*:):     IterateChildrenconst('char
 /consthome*/,user /TiXmlNodeDesktop /constTCG4_ROS*/)ros_files_comm /constdevel_isolated'/
rospack//homelib//userlibrospack.so/:Desktop /undefinedTCG4_ROS /referenceros_files_comm /todevel_isolated     /`rospackPyString_AsString/'lib
//librospack.sohome:/ userundefined/ Desktopreference/ TCG4_ROSto/     ros_files_comm`/PyString_AsStringdevel_isolated'/
rospack//homelib//userlibrospack.so/:Desktop /undefinedTCG4_ROS /referenceros_files_comm /todevel_isolated     /`rospackPyGILState_Ensure/'lib
//librospack.sohome:/ userundefined/ Desktopreference/ TCG4_ROSto/     ros_files_comm`/PyGILState_Ensuredevel_isolated'/
rospack//homelib//userlibrospack.so/:Desktop /undefinedTCG4_ROS /referenceros_files_comm /todevel_isolated     /`rospackPyErr_Print/'lib
//librospack.sohome:/ userundefined/ Desktopreference/ TCG4_ROSto/     ros_files_comm`/PyErr_Printdevel_isolated'/
rospack//homelib//userlibrospack.so/:Desktop /undefinedTCG4_ROS /referenceros_files_comm /todevel_isolated     /`rospackPyImport_Import/'lib
//librospack.sohome:/ userundefined/ Desktopreference/ TCG4_ROSto/     ros_files_comm`/PyImport_Importdevel_isolated'/
rospack//homelib//user/librospack.soDesktop:/ TCG4_ROSundefined/ ros_files_commreference/ devel_isolatedto/     rospack`/TiXmlDocumentlib:/:librospack.soLoadFile:( charundefined  constreference* ,to  TiXmlEncoding`)TiXmlDocument':
:/LoadFilehome(/charuser /constDesktop*/,TCG4_ROS /TiXmlEncodingros_files_comm)/'devel_isolated
//rospackhome//libuser//librospack.soDesktop:/ TCG4_ROSundefined/ ros_files_commreference/ devel_isolatedto/             rospack`/TiXmlNodelib:/:librospack.soNextSiblingElement:( charundefined  constreference* )to  const`'TiXmlNode
::NextSiblingElement(char const*) const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/rosstackexe.dir/build.make:101: recipe for target '/home/user/Desktop/TCG4_ROS/ros_files_comm    /devel_isolated/rospack/bin/rosstack' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/user/Desktop/TCG4_ROS/ros_files_comm/devel_isolated/rospack/bin/rosstack] Error 1
CMakeFiles/rospackexe.dir/build.make:101: recipe for target '/home/user/Desktop/TCG4_ROS/ros_files_comm    /devel_isolated/rospack/bin/rospack' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/user/Desktop/TCG4_ROS/ros_files_comm/devel_isolated/rospack/bin/rospack] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:296: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/rospackexe.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/rospackexe.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:259: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/rosstackexe.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/rosstackexe.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'rospack': 
Command '['/home/user/Desktop/TCG4_ROS/ros_files_comm/install_isolated/env.sh', 'make', '-j4', '-l4']' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/user/Desktop/TCG4_ROS/ros_files_comm/build_isolated/rospack && /home/user/Desktop/TCG4_ROS/ros_files_comm/install_isolated/env.sh make -j4 -l4

Command failed, exiting.
```

I hope somebody can help me with this error.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/308440/cross-compiling-ros-kinetic-for-arm-cortex-a7/) by [lusim](https://answers.ros.org/users/37146/lusim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-11-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-14**:
Whenever I see someone attempting to cross-compile I post this reference to [bmwcarit/meta-ros](https://github.com/bmwcarit/meta-ros).

**Comment by [lusim](https://answers.ros.org/users/37146/lusim/) on 2018-11-14**:
Thanks for your answer. The only problem is that i can't use Yocto to build my files. I have to use buildroot.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-14**:
It wasn't an answer. I just wanted to make you aware of a Yocto-based infrastructure that typically is appealing to companies and has solved most of the issues with cross-compilation already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the solution on my own. I used TinyXml2 4.0.1 which causes problems. So I updated to a newer version.

---

Originally posted by [lusim](https://answers.ros.org/users/37146/lusim/) with karma: 16 on 2018-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-16**:
Thanks for reporting back.

I've re-opened the question as we typically don't close questions here on ROS Answers if they have an answer. We mark them as *answered* by ticking the checkmark to the left of the answer. I've done that for you.

**Comment by [crosadin](https://answers.ros.org/users/41631/crosadin/) on 2019-05-19**:
Apologies for commenting again on this thread and, indeed, mine is rather a question @lusim:
about your original statement "...dependencies compiled. (log4cxx, boost 1.58, tinyxml, python2.7)...", how did you get python2.7 compiled? I guess you succeded with the shared option, since I understood is the option then needed for ROS compilation, but no way to achieve it. Could you please share the procedure?

And @gvdhoom: I'm also using Yocto, but not for this project, since I need to have Ubuntu on target and as far as understood it can't be achieved.

**Comment by [lusim](https://answers.ros.org/users/37146/lusim/) on 2019-05-20**:
hi crosadin,
for more information about buildroot, please check [www.buildroot.org](http://www.buildroot.org).
You can build your embedded Linux system with buildroot by activating the packages you want. I actually managed building ROS Kinetic as an additional package in buildroot.

**Comment by [crosadin](https://answers.ros.org/users/41631/crosadin/) on 2019-05-24**:
Hi lusim, thanks for your feedback. I went through buildroot, but native distribution does not include my target board (NXP Sabre-AI). If I finally reach to define the right specific defconfig file, I'll share it. Bye